# How to Perform Spatial Operations in GridDB

Tags: griddb

Since the news spread out about Cyclone Biparjoy, I have been working on a project for Emergency Disaster Awareness System. I used GridDB to store the data and wanted to perform spatial operations to analyze risk zones, plan evacuation routes, identify affected areas, and assess the impact of natural disasters for my project.

The SQL query for the spatial operation is shown below:

```sql
SELECT POLYGON((0 0,204 0,204 204,0 204,0 0)) AS polygon
FROM cyclone_biparjoy;
```

The equivalent TQL query according to the GridDB documentation is as follows:

```sql
POLYGON((0 0,204 0,204 204,0 204,0 0))
```

The above command should have executed properly to build a diagonal line connecting points (0, 0) and (204, 204). However, I received the following error:

```bash
Error: Function or operator not recognized: POLYGON
```

The above error shows that the **POLYGON** function is not operational. Have I missed something here?